# Touch events spilling over onto next page?

Tags: jquery, cordova, touch

I've got a weird problem which might be something amazingly stupid that I don't know about, I'll try to explain in the hope someone can help. I'm testing this on an iPad with iOS 5.

I have `page1.html` and `page2.html`. On `page1` I have an element which I click, it runs a JS function which takes me to `page2`:

```
<div id="occasion" ontouchend="test();"></div>

function test(){
    window.location.href="page2.html";
}
```

`Page2` is empty apart from the following to tell me if a click event happens:

```
<div style="background-color:red;position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;" onclick="pageTest();">test</div>

function pageTest(){         
    alert("hello");
}
```

So when `page2` opens I get the hello alert, therefore something has carried over from the `touchevent` on the previous page?

`Page1` uses jQuery, PhoneGap, and a CSS file. If I change the `touchend` or `touchstart` to `onclick` everything is fine?

Does anyone know what could cause this, it's really annoying me!

Comment: There was a guy on the mailing list how had a similar problem. Take a look at what he did as it might help http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/2228ba2b46977171/e5072dc3424a564f

Comment: Thanks simon thats seems to be the exact problem, whats the MBP he refers to? mobile boilerplate? any idea how I get to that?

Comment: http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

Answer (score 1):

To debug this issue I recommend logging the `event` object on the second page:

```
$('div:contains(test)').on('click', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    //or if you don't have a console (GET A CONSOLE!) then you can alert the event type
    alert(event.type);
});
```

This will verify what event is firing, touch or otherwise.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in this case.

Comment: ok, so it's confirmed click is fired. any ideas how it's happening?

Comment: @mao On mobile devices `click` events fire approximately 300-700ms after `touch` events. So if you are binding to `touch` events on the first page, they can fire which transitions to the second page, then 300-700ms later the `click` event for that same `touch` event fires and since the content on the `pageX`/`pageY` coordinate has changed the `click` event fires on the new content. So the issue is that you are using a `touch` event and then a `click` event, I suggest changing them to trigger on the same event, either `touchend` or `click`.

Comment: thanks, for the explanation. Is there anyway to cancel events on unload?

Comment: @mao well you can try using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in your `touchend` event handler but I think that the two events fire independently of each other: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation